# Mudar o fundo de uma div conforme o Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, já tentei com varias maneiras mas até agora não consegui criar uma barra parecida com essa do site http://www.socket.io que se move conforme a página desce.

*me refiro a barra de galáxia, no topo

Obrigado

Comment: Isso se chama Parallax. http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perceba que existe uma [imagem de fundo](http://cdn.socket.io/website/imgs/galaxy.jpg) na `div#bar`. Se você aumentar o `height` dela dos `7px` atuais para algo como `100px`, você pode entender como que a imagem se movimenta. Ainda de olho nessa `div#bar`, percebe-se que, conforme acontece o scroll, a propriedade de estilo inline  `background-position` muda. Para replicar tal efeito, basta atrelar um evento ao scroll da janela, algo como (usando jQuery):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var x = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('#bar').css('background-position', '0 ' + parseInt(-x) + 'px');
});
```

Veja em funcionamento [aqui](http://codepen.io/caio1511/pen/OVvgBX)

Comment: Rapaz, bem bacana, você me ajudaria com uma dúvida?

Tenho um código no link abaixo.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160301/opacity-de-acordo-com-scroll-da-página