# Opacity de acordo com Scroll da página

Tags: javascript, jquery, rolamento, opacity

Tenho a seguinte complicação:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('ID').css('opacity', parseInt(1 - ($(this).scrollTop()/100)*1)); });
```

Neste código eu consigo colocar o opacity: 1; quando o scroll está no topo e ao girar apenas 1px ele já poe opacity: 0;
O que estou tentando fazer é que ele comece com 0.7 e vá sumindo aos poucos até chegar na parte de cima, eu utilizo a medida VH para deixar a página do tamanho do view e com isso, na posição 0vh ele ficaria 0.7 e na posição 100vh ele ficaria 0.1

O site é este aqui http://disk.bl.ee/beltran/clean_style.php

Comment: Seria melhor postar o trecho resolvido como resposta, em vez de incorporar no campo da pergunta. Pode manter a aceitação com quem resolveu pra você, e deixar sua resposta como complemento.

Comment: @Bacco a sim, entendi, farei isso então.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagino que queira algo como isto:

O cálculo da opacidade equivale a:

```
opacidade = valorInicial * (1 - scrollTop / 100vh)
```

Sendo o *100vh* representado pelo  `$(window).height()`.

**Javascript**:

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
  var max = 0.7; //Valor inicial, que também deve ser ajustado no css
  var opacity = max * (1 - $(this).scrollTop() / $(window).height()); 
  $('div p').css('opacity', opacity);
  $('div p span').html($('div p').css('opacity'));
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #666;
}
div p {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 6vw;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 40px;
  bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Minha opacidade é:
    <br> <span></span>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

#### [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qbt2wyo/)

Comment: perfeito, isso ficou incrível, valew.

Answer (score 2):

> na posição 0vh ele ficaria 0.7 e na posição 100vh ele ficaria 0.1

Rodando a sua função no site que você mandou, ela não se comporta como você espera. Se você tentar rodar e logar os valores no console e rolar a página pra baixo, você vai perceber que o primeiro valor retornado por ela é 0 e os subsequentes são números negativos.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('ID').css('opacity', parseInt(1 - ($(this).scrollTop()/100)*1))
  console.log(parseInt(1 - ($(this).scrollTop()/100)*1))
});
```

Aqui está a saída conforme eu uso o scroll pra baixo da página:

```
> Object { length: 1, 1 more… }
> 0
This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect.
This may not work well with asynchronous panning;
see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects
for further details and to join the discussion on related tools
and features!
> 0
> -0
> -1
> -2
> -3
```

O que é esta medida VH que você está tentando usar? Você poderia upar uma versão da sua página sem nenhuma alteração na opacidade do botão pra eu fazer uns testes aqui? Valeu.

Answer (score 2):

Graças ao nosso amigo abaixo, consegui o seguinte código que deixarei para quem também precisar deste tipo de ajuda.

```
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    var max = 0.3;
    var mim = 0.1;
    var opacity = max * (1 - $(this).scrollTop() / $(window).height());
    if (opacity > mim) {
        var opacity = opacity;
    } else {
        var opacity = mim; }
    $('ELEMENTO').css('opacity', opacity); });
```